# Erdos-Szemeredi conjecture orginal paper

Tags: reference-request, additive-combinatorics

I am looking for a link to the original paper published by Erdos and Szemeredi where they prove that
$$\max(|A+A|,|A \cdot A|) \gg |A|^{1+\epsilon}$$
for $A$ a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $+$ and $\cdot$ are as in additive combinatorics.

I can find a springerlink page charging $30 https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-0348-5438-2_19 but there seems to be nothing on arxiv or anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the following link and get the entire textbook of Springer. In that book, the paper is given. The link is "https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/bafykbzacedg73uh2ihbrns75dphh46lzdqirn53vt32ledjes7hel23wl25de?filename=G%C3%A1bor%20Hal%C3%A1sz%20%28auth.%29%2C%20Paul%20Erd%C5%91s%2C%20L%C3%A1szl%C3%B3%20Alp%C3%A1r%2C%20G%C3%A1bor%20Hal%C3%A1sz%2C%20Andr%C3%A1s%20S%C3%A1rk%C3%B6zy%20%28eds.%29%20-%20Studies%20in%20Pure%20Mathematics_%20To%20the%20Memory%20of%20Paul%20Tur%C3%A1n-Birkh%C3%A4user%20Basel%20%281983%29.pdf"